# Different cmap for different block matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, heatmap, figure

Let say I have a block matrix generated by `X = np.block([[A,B], [C,D]])`, where A,B,C,D are matrices (with the same order of magnitude). I would like to use `plt.imshow(X)`, or may be heatmap, and furthermore, each block uses different `cmap`. For example,

```
x = np.random.random((2,2))
xx = np.random.random((3,3))
y = np.random.random((2,3))

zz = np.block([
    [x, y],
    [y.T, xx]
])

plt.imshow(zz, cmap='RdBu')
```

Here we impose the same `cmap` to all four blocks, so they are not distinguisable on the plot. I want to be able to assign manually `cmap` to each block, so that we can recognize each of them. How can I do that?

Comment: hi there! please provide a reproducible code to better aid you in this!

Comment: Hi, I've added some details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

colors_range = (["lightsteelblue","cyan","blueviolet","rosybrown"])

edited_cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list ('basic_test',colors_range, N=4) 

x = np.zeros((2,2))
xx = np.ones((3,3)) * (-1)
y = np.ones((2,3))

zz = np.block([[x, y],[y.T, xx]])

plt.imshow(zz, cmap=edited_cmap)
```

Where you get:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I think I didn't well specified my question. It is edited now.

Comment: So let say each block may contain many different values. The solution  you proposed will treat these values as a unique one and assign a unique color to the whole block.

Comment: Yes, it should be. You can experiment by having multiple unique blocks, and based on that create your unique colors, and then change N=4 to equal the length of colors you have. Hope this helps!